# Email triggers Airflow DAG

Tags: triggers, airflow

We are building a data extraction DAG. The source we are extracting from will email us upon new data being available. It will also send the date for which there is new data for. How do we:

(a) - Trigger a DAG upon receiving such email?
(b) - Access email content inside the DAG (e.g. the date listed in email content)

Comment: @hussein-awala tagging in case you know : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is something in Airflow to do that, but you can use an external service to receive the email, process it and send an HTTP request to Airflow API to trigger a run. In this case you can provide the content of the email (subject, body, sender, ...) as dag run configuration, and your dag tasks can access them from `{{ dag_run.conf }}`.

To do that, you need an email server with hooks (https://www.cloudmailin.com/, https://mailnuggets.com/), you can also deploy your own server ([here](https://github.com/jsvaughan/emailtohttppost) is an example for GCP App Engine). Then you need to activate Airflow API ([doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/api.html)). Finally in the hook, you configure your hook to send an POST HTTP request as explained in [this page](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run).